# Scalar curvature from Riemannian metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, curvature

I want to compute the scalar curvature for points on an empirical manifold (sampled data).

I have already an algorithm that learns the Riemannian metric and computes geodesics, so from the metric I can compute the Christoffel symbols.
However the scalar curvature is defined in terms of Christoffel symbols and their derivatives, and I do not know how to compute the derivatives given the metric.

In particular the scalar curvature is defined as
$$ S = g^{\mu \nu} \left[  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu, \lambda} -  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \lambda, \nu} +  \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu \nu}  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{ \lambda \sigma} -  \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu \lambda}  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu \sigma}\right] $$

where $ \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu, \lambda}$ is the derivative wrt to the coordinate $x^{\lambda}$  of the Christoffel symbol $ \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu}$. With $g^{\mu \nu}$ I indicate the inverse metric, i.e. $g^{\mu \nu} = (g^{-1})_{\mu \nu}$.  ( Here I use Einstein notation so repeated symbols on upper and lower script indicate summation over that index).

Is there some some of relationship that I ignore for obtaining the derivatives of the Christoffel symbols based only on the metric in a similar vein as one computed the symbols themselves from the metric?

Comment: If you already have the Christoffel symbols computed, I don't see any issue here with taking their derivatives?

Comment: @Eletie This results in a very ugly calculation. That's why I raised the question. It could be that there was an alternative way that I was not aware of. Thank you!